# Is it possible to use a redirect (301) from a .NET Core Controller in a React app?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reactjs

I'm working with a .NET EF Core + React-Redux project, and we're currently using the .NET Controller to login (using Razor/MVC for the login/register pages). Once logged in, the user is routed to pages utilizing React components.

I'm trying to use the .NET Controller to logout, but when I click the logout link, it just takes me to a 404 error page. I've tried using a form and button for the post method, and an anchor tag (but anchor tag doesn't specify methods). I've also tried making the form call a function onSubmit, but the function call gives me a 400 error.

Is it possible to even use the Controller to logout from a React-based page?

**Account/AccountController.cs:**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Logging out...");
    await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
    logger.LogInformation("User logged out.");
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

**React Component: /Navbar.js (using Controller):**

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Navbar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form action="/Account/Logout" method="post>
                <button type="submit">Logout</button>
            </form>
        )
    }
}
```

**React Component: /Navbar.js (using axios/API call to server):**

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class Navbar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    logoutUser() {
        axios.post('/Account/Logout');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.logoutUser}>
                <button type="submit">Logout</button>
            </form>
        )
    }
}
```

**404 Error:**

```
This is the error from server: Error: Request failed with status code 404
at createError (createError.js:16)
at settle (settle.js:18)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:77)
```

**Startup.cs:**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            app.UseStatusCodePages();
            app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
            {
                HotModuleReplacement = true,
                ReactHotModuleReplacement = true
            });
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc();
            //routes =>
        //{
            //routes.MapRoute(
            //    name: "default",
            //    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            //routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
            //    name: "spa-fallback",
            //    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
        //});
    }
```

Comment: a .NET controller is a server side concept. any client, react or otherwise can be used together

Comment: @azium Do you know how I can user the .NET controller to route? I updated my post for the code I've tried. But neither one worked for me. :/

Comment: I'm guessing your expecting the result from the controller (i.e. the `RedirectToAction`) to trigger a re-direct but it isn't currently?

Comment: When using an Anchor, take the `[HttpPost]` attribute off the Controller. There is no need for it to be a Post.

Comment: @Liam Yeah, it's suppose to clear the cookies (Identity & Token), as well as redirect to the homepage. At the moment, it just redirects to the same URL route, but with a "?" after the URL, and it doesn't clear the cookies.

Comment: @TimBJames I thought Logout should be a `[HttpPost]`? Or at least that's what I've seen a lot of people say about the preferred method for logging out.

Comment: *it just takes me to a 404 error page* what's the url of this page? Can you show the HTTP here?

Comment: If the Controller is `AccountController` then the Url should just be `/Account/Logout`. Add `[HttpGet]` to the Action just to make sure. Also check you don't have any strange MVC routing going on in the startup class.

Comment: @Liam What do you mean by HTTP? I added the 404 Error I get into my post. My current URL is `localhost:65015/blocks` and when I click Logout, it just routes to `localhost:65015/blocks?`.

Comment: @TimBJames I added my `Startup.cs` to my post. I tried commenting out the `app.UseMvc` routes to see if that would change anything. I also tried using `[HttpGet]` instead. But neither change did anything :/ Still getting 400 Error. It'll route me to the correct URL (`localhost:65015/Account/Logout`), but it'll just show this on the page `Status Code: 400; Bad Request `.

Comment: normally react apps don't ever refresh the page. maybe just make your post request on a button click instead of submitting a form. then handle the results appropriately

Comment: @azium Unfortunately, that didn't work either. All these suggestions make sense, but React doesn't seem to reach the `/Account/Logout` action (if I Console.WriteLine something within the action to test if it even reaches it, it doesn't).

Comment: you don't even need to use react to test that.. just use curl or postman. if you can make it work with that then it will work in react